# Github: Pushing to protected branches with fine-grained token

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release, github-fine-grained-tokens, protected-branches

I'm using semantic release in a [Github repository](https://github.com/Th3S4mur41/demo-auto-security-release) to create automatic releases on push.
The release needs to commit package.json and CHANGELOG.md to my protected branch.

I used to provide a personal token from my admin account to allow semantic-release to push to protected branch.
In order to improve security, I wanted to replace the PT through a new [fine-grained token](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/).
So I created a fine-grained PT from the same admin account as the old PT and gave it write permission to content.
Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be enough to push to the protected branch.
[image]

Any idea which permission might be needed?

UPDATE:
Not sure this is even supported yet.
I posted the question in the [fine-grained personal token feedback discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/36441#discussioncomment-4602435)

Comment: Maybe you add that account to actors that can bypass required PRs and make sure they're not restricted to push to that branch?

Comment: Nope, force push permission didn't solve the issue... Would've been strange anyway sinece admin are allowed by default to force push

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@semantic-release/git` needs the `Contents` permission set to `Read and write` in order to be able to push to a protected branch.

`Do not allow bypassing the above settings` MUST be *unchecked* in the branch protection settings in order for this to work. `Allow force pushes` is *not* required.

Note: I find it more convenient to name your Personal Access Token secret `CI_GITHUB_TOKEN`, or anything differing from the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret provided by GitHub Actions, to differentiate them easily in your workflows (since you should probably use the PAC only for `semantic-release`).

You will also need to update your action workflow file with the following in order for this to work (otherwise `git` will keep using the default generated `GITHUB_TOKEN`):

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    persist-credentials: false # <--- this
```

Additionally, if you are using the `@semantic-release/github` plugin, you may also want to grant `Read and write` on `Issues` and `Pull requests` to allow the bot to comment on issues and PRs when a release mentions it.

If you're looking for a functional implementation (with a manual configuration checklist) of `semantic-release` in a CI pipeline, you check [the PR I made](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/pull/673) for the [`cron` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

**Important security mention [from the documentation](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/recipes/ci-configurations/github-actions.md#pushing-packagejson-changes-to-a-master-branch)**

> **Note**: Automatically populated `GITHUB_TOKEN` cannot be used if branch protection is enabled for the target branch. It is not advised to mitigate this limitation by overriding an automatically populated `GITHUB_TOKEN` variable with a Personal Access Tokens, as it poses a security risk. Since Secret Variables are available for Workflows triggered by any branch, it becomes a potential vector of attack, where a Workflow triggered from a non-protected branch can expose and use a token with elevated permissions, yielding branch protection insignificant.

This risk is greatly mitigated by using a fine-grained token, and when using the `pull_request` workflow trigger, which "prevents write permissions and secrets access to the target repository".
But a user with write access to the repository might still push a branch with a workflow exploit that would expose your Personal Access Token.

**Further reading:**

- [Using semantic-release with GitHub Actions](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/recipes/ci-configurations/github-actions.md)
- [Security hardening for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions)
- [Keeping your GitHub Actions and workflows secure Part 1: Preventing pwn requests](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Pierre C.
My repository was already configured like your description. I just switched it to fine-grained token at it is indeed working now.
So I suppose the GitHub fixed the issue in the meantime